# background and shadows became solid black

Tags: rendering, shadows, saving

in render window everything is fine but when i save it in any format like png , jpg ect. shadow and background colour become black. I didnt change anythind and i tried it with default cube. Screenshot and saved image totally different. I am new in blender and i dont know what to do.
I tried gamma exposure options but nothing changed.

[image: saved image]

[image: secreen shot]

[image: both]

Comment: The images in your question are what? The top one is the saved file and the bottom one is... the render result after hitting F12? Or the 3D Viewport in Rendered View without overlays?

Comment: after i press f12 . I want to save like it but when i save it everything goes much much darker and i cant even see parts of model anymore like the first picture

Comment: So the second picture is the _3D Viewport_? And is this Eevee or Cycles?

Comment: I pressed f12 and got second picture but when i save it i got first picture .eevee and cycles did all same . I tried both and i got same result. Black shadows and backgrounds .

Comment: @HakanUçar What version of blender are you using? Experimental versions might have bugs like this. I reccomend trying to render your image with the latest stable version which is blender 2.92, maybe the problem will be fixed.

Comment: im using 2.92 right now . I tried 2.91 and had same problem.

Comment: i install the steam version of blender and  now i can save it normally. I still dont know what the problem is but for now my problem solved . Thanks for all help